# PostgreSQL domain reflected as sqltypes.NULLTYPE

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Originally postem as an [issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4377) on the [SQLAlchemy GitHub repository](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy) but it looks like there are only bots active there.

I have two PostgreSQL domains: `isoweekday` that is based on an INT and `isoweekdays` that is a list of the former elements. Both domains add some checks like no duplicates, no empty list, only values from `<1, 7>` range, etc.

```
CREATE DOMAIN isoweekday AS INT
CHECK(...);

CREATE DOMAIN isoweekdays AS isoweekday[]
CHECK(...);
```

I've created SQLAlchemy custom types, like so:

```
class ISOWeekDayDomain(types.UserDefinedType, types.Integer):
    def get_col_spec(self, **kwargs):
        return 'isoweekday'


class ISOWeekDaysDomain(types.UserDefinedType, ARRAY):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'item_type' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['item_type'] = ISOWeekDayDomain

        super(ISOWeekDaysDomain, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_col_spec(self, **kwargs):
        return 'isoweekdays'
```

and then defined a column:

```
Column(
    ISOWeekDaysDomain, nullable=False, server_default=text('ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]')
)
```

Creating migrations using Alembic went well, and it outputted the following statement:

```
op.add_column(
    u'config',
    sa.Column(
        'dow',
        ISOWeekDaysDomain(),
        server_default=sa.text(u'ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]'),
        nullable=False,
    ),
)
```

After applying migrations on the database, I'm getting the following warning:

```
sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py:2683: SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'isoweekday[]' of column 'dow'
```

Running alembic yields a new database migration that alters the previously added column with `sqltypes.NULLTYPE`.

```
op.alter_column(u'tent_crawling_config', 'dow',
           existing_type=sa.NullType(),
           nullable=False,
           existing_server_default=sa.text(u'ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]'))
```

The `domains` dictionary passed to `_get_column_info` contains both created domains and during execution it enters the [dialects/postgresql/base.py#L2677](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#L2677) block.

What am I missing? How to register my custom types that map the domains so the reflection API recognises them?

I'm using `SQLAlchemy==1.2.14` and PostgreSQL `v11`